# how do i get rid of axios error uncaught (in promise)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, error-handling, axios

I am facing the error that uncaught(in promise) in console, its axios related error, I here pasted the code userSearch.jsx file code, where error showing at the end of function's last bracket ? at the end of function's last bracket, I am getting cross sign, why ? and what's the real error?

```js
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import GithubContext from "../../context/github/GithubContext";
import AlertContext from "../../context/alert/AlertContext";
import { searchUsers } from "../../context/github/GithubActions";

function UserSearch() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')

  const { users, dispatch } = useContext(GithubContext)
  const { setAlert } = useContext(AlertContext)

  const handleChange = (e) => setText(e.target.value)

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (text === '') {
      setAlert('Please enter something', 'error')
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_LOADING' })
      const users = await searchUsers(text)
      dispatch({ type: 'GET_USERS', payload: users })

      setText('')
    }
  }



  return (
    <div className='grid grid-cols-1 xl:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 mb-8 gap-8'>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className='form-control'>
            <div className='relative'>
              <input
                type='text'
                className='w-full pr-40 bg-gray-200 input input-lg text-black'
                placeholder='Search'
                value={text}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <button
                type='submit'
                className='absolute top-0 right-0 rounded-l-none w-36 btn btn-lg'
              >
                Go
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      {users.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "CLEAR_USERS" })}
            className='btn btn-ghost btn-lg'
          >
            Clear
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserSearch;
```

ERROR SHOWING IN CONSOLE

```
GET https://api.github.com/search/users?q=brad 401
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:220
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:58
request @ Axios.js:109
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:131
wrap @ bind.js:9
searchUsers @ GithubActions.js:16
handleSubmit @ UserSearch.jsx:21
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430

UserSearch.jsx:26 //ITS ERROR SHOWING BY THE END OF FUCNTION'S LAST BRACKET, ITS SHOWING CROSS SIGN ERROR AT THE END OF OF BRACKET
 
Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
handleSubmit @ UserSearch.jsx:26
await in handleSubmit (async)
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
```

GithubAction.js file where axios is added

```js
import axios from 'axios'
const GITHUB_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_URL
const GITHUB_TOKEN = process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN

const github = axios.create({
  baseURL: GITHUB_URL,
  headers: { Authorization: `token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}` },
})

// Get search results
export const searchUsers = async (text) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    q: text,
  })

  const response = await github.get(`/search/users?${params}`)
  return response.data.items
}

// Get user and repos
export const getUserAndRepos = async (login) => {
  const [user, repos] = await Promise.all([
    github.get(`/users/${login}`),
    github.get(`/users/${login}/repos`),
  ])

  return { user: user.data, repos: repos.data }
}
```

Comment: There's no axios in your visible code. It's in `searchUsers`. Please share a runnable [mcve]. 401 means you're unauthenticated.

Comment: can you look at the question one more time? I edited it, and mention axios code file

Comment: Thanks, but same comment: the server says you're not authenticated. Is `GITHUB_TOKEN` defined and valid (issued by GitHub or whatever)? This doesn't appear related to React in any way, just a matter of setting up your request to the API properly.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your Error console `GET https://api.github.com/search/users?q=brad 401` has the error code 401, which indicates the user is unauthorized, hence GitHub is rejecting your API request. Probably the token is incorrect or expired.

The second error related to Axios,

`Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}`

This happens because the API call to GitHub fails with a 401 error code and you have not implemented any error handling mechanism in your code to properly catch the errors and process them.

In `UserSearch.jsx` modify the `handleSubmit` function to use try-catch block

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    if (text === "") {
      setAlert("Please enter something", "error");
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: "SET_LOADING" });
      const users = await searchUsers(text);
      dispatch({ type: "GET_USERS", payload: users });

      setText("");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.data.error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This happens because the API call to GitHub fails with a 401 error
> code and you have not implemented any error handling mechanism in your
> code to properly catch the errors and process theme.

I was facing same issue when I read this answer and I went back to check my code to realize that, while I was returning a value in

```
doSomething
.catch(error) { reject(false) }
```

I wasn't receiving it in the caller function's `catch` block as such

```
doSomethingCaller
.catch(error) { }
```

Once you write some error handling code, it stops displaying the error.